# how to save stream of image in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

NOTE: this is windows app, sql server as database, ado.net.

i insert images in datagridview temporarily then loop through them and save each row in database.
[image] 
i know how to insert stream from picturebox like this

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO KeyWord (ItemName, DateEntry,image, imageindex) VALUES (N'" + listBoxI.ToString() + "', GETDATE(), @image, 1)", cn);
cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic", pic);
try
{
    cn.Open();
    cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}
```

i want to replace `pictureBox1` with `dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value`

my question is how to save images from datagridview?

Comment: Is `Cells[1]` is a `DataGridViewImageColumn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go like this:

```
Image myImg = (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value as Image);
myImg.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Or in one line without the usage of a variable:

```
(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value as Image).Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

You know that the value of `DataGridViewImageColumn` is `Image` hence the conversion is safe.